# ISO 8859-7 parsing in android

Tags: android, xml, web

can we parse iso-8859-7 in Android?
If so can any one give me an example?
i have been trying to parse an XML with the encoding ISO 8859-7 in my app and cant seem to parse it. can anyone shed some light on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like

```
InputStream inputStream = createInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1");
InputSource is = new InputSource();
is.setCharacterStream(isr);

SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
MyHandler handler = new MyHandler();
parser.parse(is, handler);
```